# android rxjava sort list with comparator class

Tags: android, sorting, collections, rx-java, rx-android

I started to use rxjava with my android projects. I need to sort returning event list from api call. I wrote comparator class to sort list :

```
public class EventParticipantComparator {

    public static class StatusComparator implements Comparator<EventParticipant> {

        @Override
        public int compare(EventParticipant participant1, EventParticipant participant2) {
            return participant1.getStatus() - participant2.getStatus();
        }
    }
}
```

I can use this class with classic Collections class.

```
Collections.sort(participants, new EventParticipantComparator.StatusComparator());
```

how can I achieve this situation with reactive way ? **also if there are any way to sort list asynchronously, I will prefer that way.**

Reactive way without sorting list :

```
dataManager.getEventImplementer().getParticipants(event.getId())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Subscriber<List<EventParticipant>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(List<EventParticipant> eventParticipants) {

                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If I had not read the Javadoc for [`Collections.sort()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-java.util.Comparator-), I would have recommended something like [`map`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#map(rx.functions.Func1))`(list -> Collections.sort (list, comparator))` to convert it into a sorted array; here, `map` is the observable mapper.

However, the `sort` method above is an in-place sorting algorithm, which affect the underlying array rather than returning the fully sorted array. So instead you should do something like this:

```
dataManager.getEventImplementer().getParticipants(event.getId())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .map(unsortedList -> {
                List<EventParticipant> sortedList = new ArrayList<>(unsortedList);
                Collections.sort(sortedList, new EventParticipantComparator.StatusComparator());
                return sortedList;
            })
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<List<EventParticipant>>() {
                // ... etc.
            });
```

This will sort each incoming `List<EventParticipant>` individually and asynchronously.

Comment: well, your way is looking good for me. do you know about toSortedList() function of rxjava ? how can I pass StatusComparator function to toSortedList() function.

Comment: You might use [`toSortedList(comparator)`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#toSortedList(rx.functions.Func2)) if you were so inclined. However, this would only work if the underlying objects in the observable were `EventParticipant`s, and not the lists themselves. The way you wrote it, it seemed like the output of the method `getParticipants()` was `Observable<List<EventParticipant>>`.

Comment: yeah, `getParticipants()` function's returning value is `Observable<List<EventParticipant>>`. thanks for your answer. I'm accepting your post.

Comment: what is the reason of copying the collection in your snippet?

Comment: I didn't want to modify the underlying list that was passed to us by reference. In general, you want to avoid side-effects because it makes life hard for anyone using your code. I copied to avoid that side effect.

Answer (score 15):

This solution is similar to the accepted answer, but uses Rx operators to 1) split array into objects 2) sort by the instances Comparable implementation 3) do it on a dedicated computation thread;

```
dataManager.getEventImplementer().getParticipants(event.getId())
    .flatMap(Observable::from)
    .toSortedList()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(sortedList -> {...}, error -> {...});
```

Note that it's preferred to use Schedulers.io for network/disk writes, Schedulers.computation for computations like sorting

Comment: yes you right, thanks for `Schedulers.computation()` tips.

Comment: I think the map() operation should be flatMap().

Answer (score 7):

I am assuming the `getParticipants()` method returns `Observable<List<EventPartcipant>>`.

In the below snippet, I first convert the `Observable<List<EventPartcipant>>` to `Observable<EventParticipant>` using the `flatMap()` operator. This observable will emit each `EventParticipant` one at a time. Now by using the `toSortedList()` operator I can act on two `EventParticipant` object at a time just like `Comparator<EventParticipant>::compareTo` expects.

In the other solutions, sorting operators are applied after `.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())`, which means the actual sorting happens on the UI thread.

I modified this to let the API call execute on IO scheduler, sorting on the computation scheduler and finally your sorted list on the UI thread.

```
getParticipants().flatMap(new Func1<List<EventParticipant>, Observable<EventParticipant>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<EventParticipant> call(List<EventParticipant> eventParticipants) {
            return Observable.from(eventParticipants);
        }
    }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
      .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
      .toSortedList(new Func2<EventParticipant, EventParticipant, Integer>() {
                @Override
                public Integer call(EventParticipant eventParticipant, EventParticipant eventParticipant2) {
                    return new StatusComparator().compare(eventParticipant, eventParticipant2);
                }
    }).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
      .subscribe(new Action1<List<EventParticipant>>() {
                @Override
                public void call(List<EventParticipant> eventParticipants) {
                    // Your sorted list on UI thread.
                }
    });
```

Answer (score 6):

There is also one more way to sort list

```
dataManager.getEventImplementer().getParticipants(event.getId())
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .flatMapIterable(participants -> participants)
        .toSortedList((p1,p2) -> {p1.getStatus() - p2.getStatus()})
        .subscribe(new Subscriber<List<EventParticipant>>() {
            // ... etc.
        });
```

Answer (score 6):

Kotlin version:

```kotlin
    disposable.add(interactor.getItemList() //It returns Observable<ItemListResponseModel>
        .compose(threadTransformer.applySchedulers())
        .flatMapIterable { list -> list }
        .toSortedList { p1, p2 ->
            (p1?.name ?: "").compareTo(p2?.name ?: "")
        }
        .subscribe({ items ->
            //...
        }, { throwable ->
            //..
        }))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do like this :

```
Observable.from(list)
        .sorted((o1, o2) -> o1.name.compareTo(o2.name))
        .toList()
        .subscribe(
            sortedList -> sortedList,
            error -> error);
```

Kotlin :

```
list.sortBy { it.name }
```